# Listview's items grayed out after setting the listview's adapter in a button's onclicklistener...?

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a issue in my app; in my app, I refine listviews adapter and it's items using buttons, but when I click a button like "Show all records", the items in the listview are grayed out.

I think the code speaks for itself:

```
show_all_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Rest_menu menu = new Rest_menu();
                menu = (Rest_menu)v.getTag();
                myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(), menu.all_array);

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
```

as you can see, by clicking show_all_button, the listview's adapter sets to show all items, and the items are shown, but rows are grayed out. what can I do to make them Not grayed out?
EDIT: after some coding, edited the adapter, and here's the code of the listview's adapter:

```
public class foodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {


    Context context;
    public Food[] iteminarow;
    public foodAdapter(Context context,Food[] iteminarow)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem,iteminarow);
        this.context=context;
        this.iteminarow=iteminarow;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView foodname;
        TextView foodprice;
        TextView foodinfo;
        public ViewHolder(TextView foodname,TextView foodprice,TextView foodinfo)
        {
            this.foodname=foodname;
            this.foodprice=foodprice;
            this.foodinfo=foodinfo;
        }
    }//end of ViewHolder

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView name,price,info;
        Food f = (Food)this.getItem(position);

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater LI = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = LI.inflate(R.layout.listitem,parent,false);
            name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodname);
            price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodprice);
            info=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodinfo);
            convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(name, price, info));
        }//end of if



        else {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        name = holder.foodname;
        price = holder.foodprice;
        info = holder.foodinfo;
        }//end of else

        name.setText(f.getName().toString());
        price.setText(f.getPriceString());
        info.setText(f.getInfo().toString());

        return convertView;
    }


}//end of adapter
```

Comment: Please provide the source code of `myAdapter`.

Comment: waht do you by `grayed out` ?

Comment: it's interesting that when I change the context function in this line:

myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(**getApplicationContext()**, menu.all_array)

to **getBaseContext()** the grayed outing of the listview item's are solved...

can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `getApplicationContext()` in Activities. Use `this` or `YourActivity.this`.

- `getBaseContext()` - gets you context for your current activity (but
  you should use Context instead) and can be destroyed when activity is
  destroyed
- getApplicationContext()` - app global context which is the same for
  all activities through the life cycle.

If you want to set an adapter for your view, use your activity's context like `YourActivity.this` (`baseContext` does the trick, but Google does not recommend using it).

Comment: I just had same issue, replaced `getApplicationContext()` by `getBaseContext()`, and it worked. But can you be a bit more specyfic why to use one or another, and why with the first one the list is greyed out?

Comment: Using `getBaseContext` can be null in case of it's activity was destroyed, so using ActivityName.this (Context). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15875817/1657823) for explanation of  contexts.